# Open repo using gitkraken got stuck in a loop

Tags: repo, gitkraken

I have cloned a repo using gitkraken successfully but unable to open that repo. It is in a loop. Please let me know what need to be done to open repo.

Thank you

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109615/gitkraken-stuck-at-opening-repo

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure if you mean that GitKraken is just circling around and around and not opening properly. If that is it, then I had the same problem. I had done some work in Excel and Notepad++ and then opened GitKraken to promote it back to Gitlab. GitKraken just circled around. Worked out that these other programs had taken a lock on the files and so closed them. Closed GitKraken, opened it again and it was all ready to stage my changes.

You do not mention if you have any files open in your local repo, but if you do, close everything and then just reopen GitKraken.