# Gitkraken white screen can not be used

Tags: gitkraken

Gitkraken white screen, every few seconds will return to the original, then will continue to white screen and VScode expansion host unexpectedly terminated:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I had the same problem with Gitkraken 2.2, 2.6, 3.3. Only can use Gitkraken 1.4 now.

Comment: After check gitkraken release-note, [v1.5.1](https://support.gitkraken.com/release-notes/1x#version-1-5-1) Fixed a white screen issue that some Windows users were experiencing. Maybe  v2.x and v3.x has the same issue again.

Comment: This might come in handy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109615/gitkraken-stuck-at-opening-repo/50602215#50602215

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I could open a fresh new repository but my usual one crashed gitkraken in the exact same fashion.

I solved it by guessing it was the display rendering of all the branches that messed up and by chance found the cause :
In Preference->UI Preference, uncheck the "Show toolbar icon label" and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I had the same issue. I am running WIN 10 and a NVidia graphic card. I am not sure the problem, but it has to do with the graphics card. I had to go into the NVidia control panel for 3D and told it to use the integrated video card for GitKraken. This was also causing my Visual Studio Code not to run and that fixed it also (there is a --disable-gpu for VC).